# Scatter plot combined with line chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am doing a compensation plot
I need to make a line chart with 30 grades, each having a min and max.(low and high salary within that range) On top of that, I need to plot specific employees within the grade.

The x axis are the 30 grades, the Y axis are the wages min and max overall.

I can do a line graph which is fine for the first part and I can do a scatter plot which looks fine for the second part but when I try to do a combo to combine both, I get garbage.

Been working on this since yesterday. I don't need a secondary axis (I don't think)

Comment: Use an xy plot for both?  Format 1 to show lines and one as just points.  A line chart doesn't use xvalues (although it can label the evenly spaced points on the x axis.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a stacked column chart to define your ranges.  Then overlay an XY/Scatter chart for each employee to show their position.  For this solution, you'll want the XY/Scatter to plot to a secondary axis to better control the formatting.

[image]

Comment: I wrote a tutorial about this recently: [Salary Chart: Plot Markers on Floating Bars](http://peltiertech.com/salary-chart-plot-markers-on-floating-bars/).

Comment: Nice stuff. Exactly what I needed. Thanks Dav & Jon!